# list-comprehensions problem in python - list dispear after run once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to use list-comprehensions see link here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

but it create generator instead of return list

And when I try to convert it to list- it work only once, and then the list disappear

```
 values=[3,"fasdf",99]

 vv=(str(x) for x in values)

 vv

<generator object <genexpr> at 0x047D2F08>
 list(vv)

['3', 'fasdf', '99']

 list(vv)

[]

values


[3, 'fasdf', 99]
```

Comment: Yes, generators can only be used once. Make a list to store the values so they can be used multiple times

Comment: Following up on @mousetail, the comprehension in the `()` will return a `generator`. If you just want the list in the end and don't need a generator, use square brackets: `[str(x) for x in values]`. I would advise you to read more about generators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)!

Comment: Thanks on your advice. I didn't know that () is a generator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(str(x) for x in values)` is not a list comprehension, it's a generator expression.

`[str(x) for x in values]`, on the other hand, is a list comprehension.

The first expression makes a one-time generator that gets exhausted the moment you iterate through it. The second expression places the result of that iteration into a list, so you can access the elements again.